# How to have input in Python only take in string and not number or anything else only letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures

I am a beginner in Python so kindly do not use complex or advanced code.

```
contact = {}

def display_contact():
    for name, number in sorted((k,v) for k, v in contact.items()):
        print(f'Name: {name}, Number: {number}')



#def display_contact():
# print("Name\t\tContact Number")
# for key in contact:
#    print("{}\t\t{}".format(key,contact.get(key)))

while True:
  choice = int(input(" 1. Add new contact \n 2. Search contact \n 3. Display contact\n 4. Edit contact \n 5. Delete contact \n 6. Print \n 7. Exit \n Enter "))
  
#I have already tried


  if choice == 1:
    while True:
      try:
        name = str(input("Enter the contact name "))
        if name != str:
      except ValueError:
        continue
      else:
        break

    while True:
      try:
        phone = int(input("Enter number "))
      except ValueError:
        print("Sorry you can only enter a phone number")
        continue
      else:
        break
    contact[name] = phone
    
  elif choice == 2:
    search_name = input("Enter contact name ")
    if search_name in contact:
      print(search_name, "'s contact number is ", contact[search_name])
    else: 
      print("Name is not found in contact book")
      
  elif choice == 3:
    if not contact:
      print("Empty Phonebook")
    else: 
      display_contact()
      
  elif choice == 4:
    edit_contact = input("Enter the contact to be edited ")
    if edit_contact in contact:
      phone = input("Enter number")
      contact[edit_contact]=phone
      print("Contact Updated")
      display_contact()
    else:
      print("Name is not found in contact book")
      
  elif choice == 5:
    del_contact = input("Enter the contact to be deleted ")
    if del_contact in contact:
      confirm = input("Do you want to delete this contact Yes or No? ")
      if confirm == 'Yes' or confirm == 'yes':
        contact.pop(del_contact)
      display_contact
    else:
      print("Name is not found in phone book")



  elif choice == 6:
    sort_contact = input("Enter yes to print your contact")
    if sort_contact in contact:
      confirm = input("Do you want to print your contact Yes or No? ")
      if confirm == 'Yes' or confirm == 'yes':
        strs = [display_contact]
        print(sorted(strs))     
    else:
      print("Phone book is printed.")
  else:
        break
```

I tried but keep getting errors and I can't fiugre out how to make it only take string or letter as input and not numbers.

```
if choice == 1:
    while True:
      try:
        name = str(input("Enter the contact name "))
        if name != str:
      except ValueError:
        continue
      else:
        break
```

it is not working my code still accepts the ans in integer and string.

I am a beginner so I might have made a lot of mistakes. Your patience would be appreciated.

Comment: A string can contain digits... What exact characters do you want to allow?

Comment: Just letters a-z and no numbers or no special characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex with [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch):

```
import re

while True:
    name = input("Enter the contact name ")
    if re.fullmatch(r'[a-zA-Z]+', name):
        break
```

Or use the case-insensitive flag: `re.fullmatch(r'[a-z]+', name, flags=re.I):`

Comment: Thanks you so much is works like a charm, thanks again. I am going to have to take a closer look at this to try to fully understand how it works.

Comment: It checks whether the input string is only composed of a-zA-Z characters, with a minimum of 1 character. I added a link to the documentation.

Comment: I am going to have to keep this piece of code for future reference with the explanation you just gave me so I could reference back to it.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted that you are a beginner, I'm adding this piece of code
as a "custom-made" validation, just so you can check how you would do something like this by your own .

Note: @mozway gave a MUCH BETTER solution, that is super clean, and I recommend it over this one.

```
def valid_input(input: str):
    # Check if any char is a number 
    for char in input:
        if char.isdigit():
            print('Numbers are not allowed!')
            return False
    return True


while True:
    name = input("Enter data:")
    if valid_input(name):
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this answer from another website:

```
extracted_letters = " ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", numlettersstring))
```

First, `import re` to use the re function.
Then let's say that numlettersstring is the string you want only the letters from.
This piece of code will extract the letters from numlettersstring and output it in the extracted_letters variable.